# How to use cx_freeze with python, selenium and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, exe, cx-freeze

I can't really find any information online about doing this, but I have a python file web scrapes JavaScript loaded and used a tkinter based interface. I need this to be an executable, so that other people can use it without having to have python chromedriver already installed. I want to do this with cx_freeze as pyinstaller is giving me trouble. How would I go about this. What do I do? Does anyone have any recourses to help me?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I already told you I couldnt find anything for this type of thing.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555451/launching-selenium-based-stand-alone-exe-without-chrome-installed) answer your question?